# Bash script look for a file type in a given folder

Tags: macos, bash, unix

I have a bit of a problem. I'm trying to write a script that looks for all files of a given type (php) in a given directory. If it doesn't find it, it goes through all the sub-directories in the parent directory. If it finds it then, it performs a given operation and breaks.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function findPHP(){
  declare -a FILES
  FILES=$(find ./ -type f -name \*.php)
  for f in $FILES
  do
    echo "Processing $f file..."
    # take action on each file.
  done
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: And what is the problem you are having?

Comment: The files array always seems to be empty. I'm not sure is it because I'm not creating the array properly or if it is because it is not going through the sub-directories.

Comment: Your script looks OK to me...  perhaps drop the `-type f` option to `find`, but otherwise I would expect it to work.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks, tried it but still no joy. Putting echos on the key point I see the function is called but nothing after the do statement.

Comment: If I add echo ${#FILES[@]} this returns one

Comment: Add `set -x` to the top of your script in order to debug it.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the function. But just want to make sure, are you calling the function in the script ? #!/bin/bash function findPHP(){ declare -a FILES FILES=$(find ./ -type f -name \*.php) for f in $FILES do echo "Processing $f file..." # take action on each file. done } findPHP I tried above script and got this # ./test.sh Processing ./test.php file... Processing ./info.php file...

Comment: maybe try (find . -type...) instead of (find ./ -type...)?

Comment: what does echo"$FILE" print? also, could your processing go in a script that you could pass as a command to the -exec parameter of find?

Answer (score -1):

When using `$(...)` the shell doesn't treat *any* characters within the parentheses as special (unlike the similar backquote syntax), which suggests that the `*` does not need to be escaped.  The `find` command is probably literally seeing `\*`.  Try removing the backslash.

Comment: I just wrote a script where I used no backslash and it worked just fine.  A `\*` is not needed, `*` is enough (inside `$(...)`).

Comment: I don't fully understand the documented difference between backquotes and `$(...)` myself, but it regards the how backslashed '$', '\`', and '\' are handled, not backslashed '*'. To see how the difference is handled, try setting `a=5`, then playing with `echo $(echo $a)`, `echo $(echo \$a)`, `echo \`echo $a\``, and `echo \`echo \$a\``.